# Problem with Mediascanner class of android while connecting USB to device

Tags: android

While connecting USB to the device It is showing the following error without showing the content of USB. It is not reading the content of USB. The media scanner class started and also getting finished but no content is displayed and showing the following error.

ERROR/NVOMXMetadataRetriever(1161): Error creating metadata extractor for: /mnt/usbdisk/
 ERROR/MediaScanner(1161): new omx scanner
ERROR/MediaScanner(1161): process file: /mnt/usbdisk/

What is the solution to process all the files with mediasanner class while connecting USB to the device

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the USB drive from Android while it's mounted. The media scanner runs right after the USB is unmounted to scan for any changes that have happened while it couldn't access it. It really should not be running in the case you show above. Perhaps someone is calling it directly through MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() ?